# Did anyone succeed to implement EdDSA verification using solidity?

Tags: solidity, evm, cryptography

I am trying to implement EdDSA verification using solidity as all my contracts are written in solidity.I wanted to upgrade it to use EdDSA algorithm, but I found no packages that support it that are production ready.I found Geth-snarks implementation that requires points on the curve as input.I wanted a implementation that takes in a compressed public key and {R,s} to verify the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some reference, you can check below:

- https://github.com/HarryR/ethsnarks/blob/master/contracts/EdDSA.sol
- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-665

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - OP was looking for EdDSA, not ECDSA

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation of EDDSA signature verification with sha512 digest (based on this [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032)).

https://github.com/rdubois-crypto/FreshCryptoLib/blob/master/solidity/src/FCL_eddsa.sol

Answer (score 0):

I recently have open-sourced the library for message verification on Farcaster, you can use Ed25519.sol from there.

https://github.com/pavlovdog/farcaster-solidity/blob/main/contracts/Test.sol#L58

```
    bool valid = Ed25519.verify(
      public_key,
      signature_r,
      signature_s,
      message_hash
    );
```

Verification currently takes about 1m gas, which can be reduced by using ZK proofs.

Answer (score -1):

Openzepplin has a library that supports ECDSA operations here https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/cryptography